# Accessing JSON values with jasmine-node / frisby

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, frisby.js

I am trying to construct a test that will validate the error message received for a bad request to an API. I am using node-jasmine and frisby to write the tests but having trouble accessing the JSON values with dot notation.

```
 var frisby = require('frisby');
    frisby.create('JSON Error')
      .put('url', {
      }, {json: true})
      .expectStatus(400)
      .expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
      .auth('username', 'password')
      .afterJSON(function (body) {
        //changed values
        expect(body.error.newEmail).toMatch('missing-required-key'),
        expect(body.error.oldEmail).toMatch('missing-required-key')
      })
    .toss();
```

Expected JSON response body

```
{
"error": {
"newEmail": "missing-required-key",
"oldEmail": "missing-required-key"
}
}
```

Test results in following error:

```
Cannot read property newEmail of undefined
```

I have wrote a similar test in Postman which works, I am trying to convert these tests into something that can be used by node.js.

Postman working example:

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);

//error messages

var newEmailError = body.error.newEmail;
var oldEmailError = body.error.oldEmail;

tests["New Email Error Message"] = newEmailError === "missing-required-key";
tests["Old Email Error Message"] = oldEmailError === "missing-required-key";
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the endpoint supplied was incorrect, test is valid with the correct endpoint!

Answer (score -1):

you need too do that:

```
frisby.create('GET JSON data with parameters')
    .get('your_json_url.com')
    .expectStatus(200)
    .expectHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .expectJSON({ 'error': {
            'newEmail': 'missing-required-key'
        }})
    .toss();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.